# Changing Android Device orientation with ADB

Tags: android, automation, adb, ui-automation

I'm using Android 4.4 on a real device and I want to set the device orientation via `adb`.  I don't want it done with uiautomator since it won't last after the termination of the uiautomator code.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android emulator - Screen rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420617/android-emulator-screen-rotation)

Answer (score 79):

Instead of using "adb shell content", there's a more clean way by using "adb shell settings". They are doing the same thing, put value to settings provider.

```
adb shell settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0  #disable auto-rotate
adb shell settings put system user_rotation 3  #270° clockwise
```

- `accelerometer_rotation: auto-rotation, 0 disable, 1 enable`
- `user_rotation: actual rotation, clockwise, 0 0°, 1 90°, 2 180°, 3 270°`

Comment: On firestick my screen was rotating automatically and i had to set user_rotation to 0, which stopped it, not sure if they have these values meaning different things (command used: settings put system user_rotation 0)

Comment: This helped recover my Waydroid instance after I maximized an application and everything rotated.

Answer (score 73):

You may first need to turn off the automatic rotation:

```bash
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

Rotate to landscape:

```bash
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1
```

Rotate portrait:

```bash
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

Comment: You can also use `2` and `3` for upside-down portrait and reverse landscape respectively.

Comment: First you have to run ```adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0``` to turn off the automatic rotation

Comment: How do I avoid turning off the automatic rotation? and how do I get and restore its original value?

Comment: Worked like a charm, disabling automatic rotation was important.

Comment: ``content insert --uri content://settings/system``  is exactly the same thing as writing ``settings put system``

Answer (score 32):

Disable `accelerometer_rotation` and set the `user_rotation`

---

**`user_rotation Values:`**

```
0           # Protrait 
1           # Landscape
2           # Protrait Reversed
3           # Landscape Reversed
```

**`accelerometer_rotation Values:`**

```
0           # Stay in the current rotation
1           # Rotate the content of the screen
```

---

#### Example using adb:

```
adb shell settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0
adb shell settings put system user_rotation 3
```

#### Example programmatically:

```
import android.provider.Settings;

// You can get ContentResolver from the Context
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, 3);
```

Answer (score 6):

*wm* cmd can be used to set the user rotation on adb shell

```
wm help
user-rotation [free|lock] [-d DISPLAY_ID] [rotation]
Set user rotation mode and user rotation.
```

Example:

```
wm user-rotation lock 0
wm user-rotation lock 1
```