# Android Studio emulator reverse landscape orientation

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am working on an app in Android Studio and couldn't find a way to test reverse landscape in the emulator. (I don't own an Android device so that is not an option.) Is there some way to do this or does the emulator not have this function?

EDIT: I know the keyboard command for orientation but it only toggles standard layout. I wanted to know if there was a way to set emulator in reverse layouts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching to landscape mode in Android Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator)

Comment: not quite, trying specifically to find keyboard command for reverse orientation, ctr + f12/11 just toggle between portrait and landscape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This help me [Changing Android Device orientation with ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864385/changing-android-device-orientation-with-adb)

So first run

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

Than for:

PORTRAIT

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

REVERSE_LANDSCAPE

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1
```

REVERSE_PORTRAIT

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:2
```

LANDSCAPE

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:3
```