# Android TV Emulator as rotated and can not be be restored

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, screen-orientation, android-tv, android-emulator-plugin

I am facing a weird problem from my Android TV emulator. The issue is, the Emulator is somehow rotated including its frame and I can not restore the normal state of my emulator.

I have tried **Running adb command** [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864385/changing-android-device-orientation-with-adb) and I ran `adb shell settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0`  and `adb shell settings put system user_rotation 3` that forcefully rotates the tv inside screen but not the whole frame.

[image: When I was trying the force rotation using command]

Here is my current state of my tv emulator.

[image: CurrentState]

It'll be very nice if I get rid of the issue with your help. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like if the latest Android Studio version `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1`
`Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973, built on August 17, 2023


Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.`

Has this issue. Hopefully it will be automatically fixed with the next patch version.